# Why does my PySpark program hang in between as follows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have written a PySpark program and when I run it , it prints a lot of output and then suddenly hangs with the following statement on the screen

```
[Stage 11:===================================>                   (65 + 1) / 100]
```

It doesn't progress from here at all. Is it that the program has actually ended or something else wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That is very common when you use `Apache Spark` there might be several problems or exceptions which aren't showed in the terminal, however to debug this you can read what happened while running, but **depends** on your Apache Spark current installation (that's why I don't post a link), you can find more information on this doc. [Monitoring and Logging in Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#monitoring-and-logging)

You have to search for this **WebUI**, in the **Description** Column you can click on **+ details** (to get that you need to click the **job** you will debug), and if you keep going you will find more and more information.

[image: Failing Job]
[image: Details]

Comment: Thanks. I am going to do this now.

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar I am having problems with my current installation, that is why I don't show a proper image, however I will do it in some mins~hours.

Comment: Do you know why the "Details" does not appear in mine as well? I don't see Details... I am running on Local mode on my laptop.

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar You have to click on the blue string to get the details. I updated the picture as you can see you can find moreinformation on **+ details**.

Comment: Great, thanks. I see it. Can we see which line of my pySpark code actually failed?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar They normally say **failed**, or they don't progress and get stuck, and they tend to keep in the **Active Job** region.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues with hanging. 
Initially, my spark config was

`

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName('AppName') \
        .setMaster('local[*]')
```

`

which produced hanging, similar to yours.

`[Stage 3:=============================>                             (1 + 0) / 2]`

After changing my master's URI in my configuration, I no longer experience hanging.
`

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName('App Name') \
    .setMaster('spark://hostname-of-master:7077')
```

`

The master's URL can be found typically at `localhost:8080`